# Memorylessness by way of additional dimensions

Tags: modeling, markov-process, hidden-markov-model, differential-equations

This is a somewhat broad question that occurred to me regarding the nature of memorylessness. Namely: Is there utility in considering systems which are themselves not memoryless, but then expanding them by "hidden" dimensions to obtain memorylessness?

As an example: If we consider, say, a ball thrown through the air, and a process $X_t$ that tracks its position in 2D, then it is not memoryless, because just from a position we do not yet know the ball's velocity.

If we add an (unobserved) velocity variable, however, then suddenly we have a hidden Markov model, as the pair $(X_t, v_t)$ surely obeys the Markov property.

This seems somehow analogous to the trick of transforming higher-order ODEs into first-order by adding additional state dimensions, which appears plausible given the interrelated nature of ODEs and Markov Processes.

The question is: Have we won anything in particular with that transformation? Is it feasible to attempt Hidden Markov inference on systems whose observables are not memoryless at all?

Comment: I don't see how a thrown ball's coordinate process has memory regardless of whether you observe its velocity directly or not

Comment: @Aksakal Admittedly it's a poor example because the process is deterministic and so it makes little sense to talk about conditional probabilities. But let's imagine a thrown ball with measurement noise for the moment. Then, if we are currently at point (1, 1), the conditional probability, conditioned on "a second ago we were at (1, 2)" -, of the event "in a second we will be at (2, 0)" is zero - we are, after all, evidently in free fall. This information is not contained in only "We're currently in (1, 1)"

Comment: But if you observe a couple of coordinates then you can estimate velocity and acceleration. That makes it memoryless. As long as memory is not “very long”

Comment: @Aksakal I'm not sure whether I understand what you mean - obviously we don't need complete information of the past to infer the future. But if we consider the version with measurement noise and some prior on the initial conditions, then clearly, for some ball $B = B_\varepsilon(2, 0)$, we have $P(X_2 \in B \ | \ X_1 = (1, 1), \ X_0 = (1, 2)) \neq P(X_2 \in B \ | \ X_1 = (1, 1))$. This is not memoryless